# Parse ParseFacebookUtilsV4 login problems

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

So, recently I had a separate app rejected from the app store for using the old pre-FB 4.x SDK 'bounce user to Safari' method for logging in with Facebook.  (Guideline 10.6)

Either I'm missing something or Parse does this with ParseFacebookUtilsV4 too.  Can I set it to use an embedded webview?

Thanks to daddy warbucks.

```
[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager].loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in this file:
FBSDKLoginManager.h

```
  typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior)
    {
      /*!
       @abstract Attempts log in through the native Facebook app. If the Facebook app is
       not installed on the device, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the
       default behavior.
       */
      FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0,
      /*!
       @abstract Attempts log in through the Safari browser
       */
      FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser,
      /*!
       @abstract Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through Settings.
       If no Facebook account is signed in, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
       */
      FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount,
      /*!
       @abstract Attemps log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up

       @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
       Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
       */
      FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
    };
```

and then look in Parse's header file "PFFacebookUtils.h" for facebook login and red this:

```
/*!
 @abstract Login behavior controls whether to allow, force or prohibit Facebook Login or Inline Facebook Login.

 @discussion Default is to allow Facebook Login, with fallback to Inline Facebook Login.

 @returns The login behavior currently set.
 */
+ (FBSessionLoginBehavior)facebookLoginBehavior;

///--------------------------------------
/// @name Logging In & Creating Facebook-Linked Users
```

These two files contain the information you need in order to change the default method of sending the user to X, Y, or Z in order to log in.

Comment: what version of the PFFacebookUtils are you using? did you install it yourself or through cocoapods? i've tried using the PFFacebookUtils & PFFacebookUtilsV4 pods and can't find the code you've pasted in the PFFacebookUtils header

Comment: one sec, I'm checking on facebook sdk version, Okay, so yeah, as I suspected, I'm using the latest from Facebook the v4.4.0 SDK with the Parse SDK latest 1.7.5

Comment: I don't use Cocoapods, I won't use and can't use free libraries for the folks I work for and Cocoapods cause a bigger headache than people realize. Depending on which libraries you are pulling into your code base, it's not too difficult to just pull in the Parse and Facebook libraries or any other library for that matter

Comment: But, I'm using both the Parse SDK and the facebook SDK, but you really on need the Parse sdk, and with this you can probalby manipulate this field:+ (FBSessionLoginBehavior)facebookLoginBehavior;   this is the field that needs to be messed with to determine whether Safari does the login or whether some other way is used like the pop over stupid bounce thing or the pulling up of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed by downloading the latest Facebook SDK and the latest Parse SDK, they have been updated fairly recently. The new SDKs will take you to the Facebook App to login.

Comment: the issue is the fact that it does that, as opposed to opening a webview within the application. the question was 'how do i set up parse/pffacebookutils' to fire a webview as opposed to opening the native FB app.  FWIW i'm using cocoapods to include the latest version of PFFacebookUtils + Parse sdk.